# How to enable subdomain multisite feature for an dotnet web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wonder how to enable subdomain multisite feature for an Microsoft dotnet web application like Wordpress PHP application. For example, my Microsoft dotnet application has the domain name: example.com. When a user1 register to my application, it provides the user1 with the domain name user1.example.com. When user2 register to may application, it provides user2 with the url user2.example.com...
My question is: Does Microsoft dotnet support this technique? If yes, please tell me how to do.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of technology u r using mvc or webforms

Comment: I am using mvc.